# Populating a HTML dropdown menu through a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to populate a dropmenu as described in the heading. At the moment I've this code:

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
     <option>Choose a number</option>
     <script>
         var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
         for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {  
             document.write('<option value="' + myArray[i] +'">' + myArray[i] + '</option>');
         }
     </script>
</select>
</form>
```

This works fine, but I have a large amount of variables in my array, so i want to put the script in a javascript file as a function and then call it in the html for aesthetic purposes.

So this is what i tried in the javascript file

```
function populate(){
    var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
    for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {  
        document.write('<option value="' + myArray[i] +'">' + myArray[i] + '</option>');
    }
}
```

And then I tried to call that method in the HTML like so :

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="selectNumber" onclick="populate()">
        <option>Choose a number</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and this didn't work it just brought a new page and the numbers , but not in a dropdown menu to select from.

Any ideas on how to fix it would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't use `document.write` at all. It's used for very specific purposes and not often. You need document.createElement, appendChild in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `document.write()` the script has to be executed while loading the page.
You call the function with `onclick` which is obviously not while loading.
Instead call the function directly:

```
<select id="selectNumber">
  <option>Choose a number</option>
  <script>
     populate();
  </script>
</select>
```

The javascriptfile has to be included before the function call

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you should avoid `document.write()` and use a combination of [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)/[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) instead.

You could also avoid inline JS and use [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead:

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectNumber'),
    optionArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function populateSelectElement (element, array) {
    var newElement,
        i;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        newElement = document.createElement('option');
        newElement.textContent = optionArray[i];
        element.appendChild(newElement);
    }
}
populateSelectElement(selectElement, optionArray);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="selectNumber">
        <option>Choose a number</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then just attach a click event handler like this:

```
selectElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    populateSelectElement(this, optionArray);
});
```